# API POST request getting Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'job_title')

Tags: javascript, postgresql, api, express, postman

I have built and API with Express to POST a new job in a project I am currently working on. The GET requests work fine, also the DEL, but the POST one is not working. I am connected to a POSTGRES database.

I have defined the following path for the API:

```
app.use('/api/jobs', jobRoutes);
```

so when I send a POST request like below:

```
localhost:4000/api/jobs/createjob
```

it should work. What is also weird, is that the code was working perfectly before, but now I can't seem to figure it out anymore. I tried looking elsewhere, but I couldn't find any solution when getting this kind of error with APIs.

My API looks like the following:

```
router.post("/createjob", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {job} = req.body;
        const newJob = await pool.query("INSERT INTO job(job_title, job_department, country_id, description, expiration_date) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *", [job.job_title, job.job_department, job.country_id, job.description, job.expiration_date]);

        res.json(newJob.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})
```

I am making the POST request with Postman, and the body looks like this:

```
{
    "description": "job_description",
    "job_title": "Back End Developer"
}
```

When I send the requests, in the terminal shows this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'job_title')
```

Full code of the Routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require("../db");


// routes
// get all jobs
router.get('/alljobs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allJobs = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM job");
        res.json(allJobs.rows)

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})

// GET a single job
router.get('/job/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {id} = req.params;
        const job = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM job WHERE job_id = $1 ", [id]);
        res.json(job.rows)

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})

// create a job
router.post("/createjob", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {job} = req.body;
        const newJob = await pool.query("INSERT INTO job(job_title, job_department, country_id, description, expiration_date) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *", [job.job_title, job.job_department, job.country_id, job.description, job.expiration_date]);

        res.json(newJob.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})

// update a job
router.patch("/updatejob/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {id} = req.params;
        const {description} = req.body;
        const updateJob = await pool.query("UPDATE job SET description = $1 WHERE job_id = $2", [description, id]);

        res.json(updateJob.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})

// delete a job
router.delete("/deletejob/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {id} = req.params;
        const deleteJob = await pool.query("DELETE FROM job WHERE job_id = $1", [id]);

        res.json(deleteJob.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})

// get all countries
router.get("/countries", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const allCountries = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM countries");
        res.json(allCountries.rows)

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }

})

// //create new user
// router.post("/newuser", async (req, res) => {
//     try {
//         const {user} = req.body;
//         const newUser = await pool.query("INSERT INTO users(user_name, email, password, is_candidate, is_recruiter) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *", [user.user_name, user.email, user.password, user.candidate, user.recruiter]);

//         res.json(newUser.rows);
//     } catch (error) {
//         console.error(error.message);
//     }
// })


module.exports = router;
```

Full code of my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = require("./routes/jobRoutes");
const jobRoutes = require("./routes/jobRoutes");
const cors = require("cors");

//creates express app
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//middleware
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    console.log("req.path", req.method);
    next();
})

app.get("/status", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("connected");
  });

// for every other request
app.use('/api/jobs', jobRoutes);

// more middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    let status = err.status || 500;
    let message = err.message;
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(status).json({
        error: { message, status },
    });
});

//listen for requests
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 4000")
});
```

I tried looking elsewhere, but I couldn't find any solution when getting this kind of error with APIs. The GET and the DEL requests work as expected.

Comment: Which is the exact line that throws the error?

Comment: I’d love to know myself. The error is thrown after I send the POST request.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Are you sure that req.body is defined? You might need to use the [body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware to make sure that req.body holds what you expect it to hold